# Why cant i add Orientation property to the Style Setter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, stackpanel

When i write something like this:

```
  <Style x:Key="panelS">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
  </Style>
```

I get the error that says: *Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Orientation'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property.*

Sure i have a Dock panel with many Stackpanels in it so i want to move Stackpanel's properties to the style. But there is this error and i dont quite understand what it means and what is the workaround(..i'd wanted not to assign Orientation on every Stackpanel).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Style` isn't associated with the `StackPanel` type.

Therefore, WPF doesn't know about the `Orientation` property.  (Because that property is defined by `StackPanel`)

You can explicitly tell WPF which class defines the property by changing it to `StackPanel.Orientation`.

Alternatively, you can associate the `Style` with the `StackPanel` type by adding a `TargetType="StackPanel"` to the `<Style>` element.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a TargetType to the style, so that it knows you are talking about StackPanels.  This version should work:

```
<Style x:Key="panelS" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
</Style>
```

Comment: OOps, forgot about it! Thank you!